# Android cocos2d getting a sprite to continuously move to a dynamic position

Tags: android, sprites, movement, cocos2d

I tried using the MoveTo method in cocos2d to get a sprite to continuously follow my player sprite:

```
CCMoveTo actionMove = CCMoveTo.action(actualDuration, player.getPosition());
CCSequence actions = CCSequence.actions(actionMove);
enemy_sprite.runAction(actions);
```

However when the sprite spawns it just goes to the position the player sprite was at when it spawned, therefore it doesn't follow it continuously.
So I tried using a recursive function to get the sprite to follow the player sprite continuously:

```
CCMoveTo actionMove = CCMoveTo.action(actualDuration, player.getPosition());
CCCallFuncN actionMoveDone = CCCallFuncN.action(this, "enemySpriteMoveFinished");
CCSequence actions = CCSequence.actions(actionMove, actionMoveDone);
enemy_sprite.runAction(actions);
```

Where "enemySpriteMoveFinished" is:

```
    public void enemySpriteMoveFinished(Object sender) {
    CCSprite sprite = (CCSprite)sender;
    CCMoveTo actionMove = CCMoveTo.action(0.5f, player.getPosition());
    CCCallFuncN actionMoveDone = CCCallFuncN.action(this, "enemySpriteMoveFinished");
    CCSequence actions = CCSequence.actions(actionMove, actionMoveDone);
    sprite.runAction(actions);
    }
```

But this method turns out to be rather choppy. Anyone have any solution to getting cocos2d to move a sprite to a dynamic position continuously that's smoother?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it by updating the enemy sprite in my games update method by adding a fraction of the distance between the enemy sprite and player sprite to the enemy sprites position.

```
for (CCSprite enemySprite : _enemySprites) {
        CGPoint enemySpritePosition = enemySprite.getPosition();
        CGRect enemySpriteRect = CGRect.make(enemySprite.getPosition().x - (enemySprite.getContentSize().width),
                enemySprite.getPosition().y - (enemySprite.getContentSize().height),
                enemySprite.getContentSize().width,
                enemySprite.getContentSize().height);

        if (CGRect.intersects(playerRect, enemySpriteRect))
            CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(GameOverScreen.scene());

        enemySpritePosition.x += (player.getPosition().x - enemySprite.getPosition().x) / 50;
        enemySpritePosition.y += (player.getPosition().y - enemySprite.getPosition().y) / 50;
        enemySprite.setPosition(enemySpritePosition.x, enemySpritePosition.y);
    }
```